# CSS Media Query Hierarchy - Why Doesn't "Smaller" Media Query Render in Browser / Inspector?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries

I have several media queries, but there are two that I'm trying to use to style a certain element:

`.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a`

Here is my CSS including previous media queries:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {

     .header-column-secondary {
    width: 13%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

    #gatewaylogo {
    height: 85px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .phone-number {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    }

    .social-media {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    transform: translateY(-7%);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a 
    {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #1B3764;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #1B3764;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    }
 }
```

You can see that the media queries that are applying to `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a` are `(max-width: 1024px)` and `(max-width: 768px)`

The idea is that from 1024px - 769px, I want `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a` to get `margin-right: 60px`, and at 768px, tablet size, I want `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a` to get `margin-right: 20px`. I plan on continuing to add media queries as the browser width gets smaller - 475px, 375px, and 320px.

[image]

So why is it that at 768px, the media query doesn't render? It seems that the media query for 1024px is still getting the style and overriding it. I don't want to add `!importants`, because then I will continue to have to add `!importants` all the way down to 320px.

A problem is that I like to design from desktop to mobile - not mobile first. Any suggestions? The website is live here: http://nowordpress.gatewaywebdesign.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues in this problem:

1. viewport definition is missing
2. both `min-width` and `max-width` need to be defined to get media query in this scenario to work.

Here is some detail explanation:

There is no *rule_override_based_on_min/max_width* in media query. That is, if there are 2 media query rule-set, one is `(max-width: 1024px)` and another is `(max-width: 768px)`, there is no guarantee that rules inside `(max-width: 768px)` will override rules inside `(max-width: 1024px)` -- when conflict happens between 2 rules inside 2 different media query rule-set, the one that appear later in the CSS win. That's why you need both `min-width` and `max-width` for media query.

Here is a simple example: although `(max-width: 5000px)` is a more reasonable rule to take effect, the final background color is pink.

```css
@media (max-width: 5000px) {
    .testd {
      background: yellow;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 100000px) {
    .testd {
      background: pink;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="testd">DDD</div>
```

And David is correct, the viewport definition is missing. Without it, media query is impossible due to pixel ratio.

Answer (score 3):

Your are missing a viewport meta tag in the head of your page,  add something like the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Good luck!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a media query like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)
```

Comment: If you check /css/style.css you'll see that that's what I have now - it's still not working though.